# cdktf provider add grafana/grafana possible yet?

Tags: grafana, terraform-provider, terraform-cdk

I am currently on a deep-dive for grafana unified alerting, which led me to deep-dive into terraform, which in turn has me stuck in the middle of:

`cdktf provider add grafana/grafana`

Meaning I recognize the pain in writing exhaustive .yamls and want to abstain from actually writing them. CDKTF to the rescue. But alas, it appears grafana is not quite there yet.

In short: I appear to have problems downloading the provider, which might be a local problem, but I have also not found any sources for the grafana cdktf provider. Is there one, yet?

I searched the repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-issue: The following works just fine.

```
cdktf provider add grafana/grafana
```

It appears my companies IT prevents certain things.

Comment: Gladly. How? Sorry, I am new.

Comment: Please, check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer . Thanks,